# Как разделить один список на несколько списков?

Tags: python

Есть список:

```
a = ['2020-06-11', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-13', '2020-06-14', '2020-06-15', '2020-06-16', '2020-06-17', '2020-06-18', '2020-06-19', '2020-06-20', '2020-06-21', '2020-06-22', '2020-06-23', '2020-06-24', '2020-06-25', '2020-06-26', '2020-06-27', '2020-06-28', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-30', '2020-06-31', '2020-06-32', '2020-06-33', '2020-06-34']
```

Надо этот список разделить на 5 маленьких:

```
b = ['2020-06-11', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-13', '2020-06-14', '2020-06-15']
c = ['2020-06-16', '2020-06-17', '2020-06-18', '2020-06-19', '2020-06-20']
d = ['2020-06-21', '2020-06-22', '2020-06-23', '2020-06-24', '2020-06-25']
e = ['2020-06-26', '2020-06-27', '2020-06-28', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-30']
f = ['2020-06-31', '2020-06-32', '2020-06-33', '2020-06-34']
```

Списки `b, c, d, e, f` могут немного отличаться.

Главное, чтобы эта программа работала, при том что список `a` будет дополняться, и если в списке `a` не четное количество элементов.

Comment: Вы что-то пробовали ?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ваш вопрос  остаётся непонятен. _Надо этот список разделить на 5 маленьких_, а по какому критерию? _могут немного отличаться_, а как отличаться?

Answer (score 4):

```
In [76]: n = 5

In [77]: res = [a[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(a), n)]

In [78]: res
Out[78]:
[['2020-06-11', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-13', '2020-06-14', '2020-06-15'],
 ['2020-06-16', '2020-06-17', '2020-06-18', '2020-06-19', '2020-06-20'],
 ['2020-06-21', '2020-06-22', '2020-06-23', '2020-06-24', '2020-06-25'],
 ['2020-06-26', '2020-06-27', '2020-06-28', '2020-06-29', '2020-06-30'],
 ['2020-06-31', '2020-06-32', '2020-06-33', '2020-06-34']]

In [79]: b,c,d,e,f = res
```